# jquery function not working for form validation

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a multistep form using jQuery.

Following is my code:

```
<div id="div1">
<form>
<label>Username</label><input type="text" id="username"></input>
<label>Password</label><input type="text" id="password"></input>
</form>
<a href="#" class="next">NEXT</a>
</div>

<div id="div2">
<p>Content of Div 2</p>
</div>
```

My JS:

```
function showdiv2(){
$("#div1").hide();
$("#div2").show();
}

function validateuser(){
var username =  $("#username").val().length;
if (username >5 && username<20)
    errorUser =false;
}

function validatePassword(){
var password =  $("#password").val().length;
if (password>8 && password<20)
    errorPassword =false;
}

$('.next').click(function(){
    var errorUser = false;
    var errorPassword = false;

validateuser();
validatePassword();

if(errorUser=false && errorPassword=false){
return=true;
showdiv2();

}
else{
    return=false;
}

} );
```

The validation works fine. But I cannot get the function showdiv2() to work.

How can I achieve this? This is another similar form in Div 2 so I cannot use the submit button in div1.

Please help.

Many thanks.

Comment: you put `return` before `showdiv2()` that is why `showdiv2()` will never be called.

Comment: if i dont put return, the div2 is shown even if the fields are not validated

Comment: Your if statement is incorrect. You should use two '=' signs instead of one when comparing a variable with a value.

Answer (score 0):

you must add an action or method in ur form tag in html so that it will redirect the form info to ur JS page..:)

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/hhctcLyh/1/)**

```js
function showdiv2() {
  $("#div1").hide();
  $("#div2").show();
}

function validateuser() {
  var username = $("#username").val().length;
  if (username > 5 && username < 20)
  return true;
}

function validatePassword() {
  var password = $("#password").val().length;
  if (password > 8 && password < 20)
    return true;
}
  
$('.next').click(function() {
var _return = false;


  if (!validateuser() && !validatePassword() ) {
    showdiv2();
    _return = true;

  } else {
    _return = false;
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">
  <form>
    <label>Username</label>
    <input type="text" id="username">
    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="text" id="password">
  </form>
  <a href="#" class="next">NEXT</a>
</div>

<div id="div2">
  <p>Content of Div 2</p>
</div>
```

1. `<input type="text" id="username">` instead of `<input type="text" id="username"></input>`
2. `password.length>8 && password.length<20` instead of `password length>8 && <20`
3. `errorUser==false && errorPassword==false` instead of `errorUser=false && errorPassword=false`
4. use `var` yo define new variable in js

Comment: Thank .. but the code does not validate the form. It shows div 2 even if the fields are empty. I want div2 to show if  errorUser == false and errorPassword == false.

Comment: How i got what you want. Update the code, pls check it

Answer (score 0):

There are error in your HTML i.e. no need to close `input` tag `</input>`.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".next").click(function(){
     var urnm = $("#username").val().length;
     var pwd = $("#password").val().length;
     if(urnm >= 5 && urnm<= 20){
       if(pwd >= 5 && pwd<= 20){
         $("#div2").show();
       }
    }
    else{
      $("#div2").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks .. but this does not validate the form. I want the div2 to be shown only if everything in div1 is validated.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function showdiv2() {
                $("#div1").hide();
                $("#div2").show();
            }

            function validateuser() {

                var username = $("#username").val();
                if (username.length < 1) {
                    return true;
                }
                if (username.length > 5 && username.length < 20)
                    return false;

            }

            function validatePassword() {
                var password = $("#password").val();
                if (password.length < 1) {
                    return true;
                }
                if (password.length > 8 && password.length < 20)
                    return false;

            }

            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('.next').click(function () {

                    var errorUser = true;
                    var errorPassword = true;
                    errorUser = validateuser();
                    errorPassword = validatePassword();

                    if (errorUser === false && errorPassword === false) {
                        showdiv2();
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return  false;
                    }

                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="div1">
            <form>
                <label>Username</label><input type="text" id="username"></input>
                <label>Password</label><input type="text" id="password"></input>
            </form>
            <a href="#" class="next">NEXT</a>
        </div>

        <div id="div2">
            <p>Content of Div 2</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Try this tested code. If any help needed comment

Answer (score 0):

I defined the variables as true and it works:

```
var errorUser = true;
var errorPassword = true;
```